# Transport Calama <-> San Pedro de Atacama, Chile

Tags: public-transport, chile

What is the best (highest cost x benefit, lowest travel time) way to get from Calama to San Pedro de Atacama?

I know there are some bus companies and another companies that offer private shuttle.

Does anyone has a pricing table?
Can someone tell me the advantages and disadvantages of the two alternatives?

Comment: Please define what is 'best' for you otherwise this question is off-topic as too subjective: is it cheapest ? fastest ? most convenient ? least amount of transfers ?

Comment: The edit doesn't help. What is "best"? Some people might like a slow, leisurely journey, others might want to get there as fast as possible. Different people have different ideas about what might be a benefit, an advantage or a disadvantage (see above).

Comment: I've edited again. Better now? =]

Answer (score 2):

There are several bus companies that do the Calama to San Pedro run. They're cheap, the distance is short. Unless you're pressed for time, there's no reason not to take them.

Rome2Rio [lists](https://www.rome2rio.com/s/Calama/San-Pedro-de-Atacama) two companies, though I seem to remember there were three or four. Prices were similar.